# cd command is not working

Tags: wireless, directory, cd-command

So every time I try to navigate to a directory it gives me this message but when I navigated to my desktops directory it did just that

[image]

Comment: Did you copy and paste the command? it looks like it has some kind of non-printing character (such as a non-breaking space) in front

Comment: It looks like a Unicode whitespace character *other* than space or tab was entered just before `cd`. How you are you running that `cd` command? Pasting from a website? What site? What happens if you type `cd` on your prompt and press Enter? What happens if you type `cd`, then a space, then type `rtl` and press Tab? Does that complete the name? If so, when you press Enter, does it change to it? Please **[edit]** your question with this info, and also copy all text from the Terminal, *especially* what you've shown so far, paste it in, select what you pasted, and press Ctrl+K or click **{}**.

Comment: Have you tried other commands like `pwd` or `ls` to see if they are functioning??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like @steeldriver is correct, your example has something invisible before cd. A space would be harmless, lets consider your options if it is just a space.

In your terminal, do you see what I see?

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

I'm not sure if "shell builtin" refers to functionality from /bin/sh or a shell like /bin/bash or /bin/dash.  My first guess what that this comes from the shell, rather than sh. Make sure your environment has a $SHELL specified.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

If you fiddled around in your session, either interactively with commands like "export ..." or by running scripts or via editing .bashrc, you could cause the trouble you see. Check your SHELL variable.

Probably, you see some legal $SHELL. Make sure the output mentions a file that currently exists.

```
$ ls -la /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1099016 May 16 06:35 /bin/bash
```

Maybe you see dash or something.

Can you get a new terminal to see if the same thing happens? Each terminal will launch its own shell, problem may appear differently, or not at all. If problem is same, then it means problem is either in your configuration or in the shell files themselves.

Supposing you do have the bash package installed, or any other shell, actually, launch a new shell in that terminal (-l means login shell):

```
$ bash -l
```

Is problem same after that?

If that is a fail, I'd use the command line to install/re-install the shell programs. I've got both bash and dash:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep bash
ii  bash                      
4.4-2ubuntu1.1              amd64        GNU Bourne Again SHell

$ dpkg -l | grep dash   
ii  dash                                                            
0.5.8-2.3ubuntu1            amd64        POSIX-compliant shell
```

In your situation, I'd try a reinstall

```
$ apt-get install --reinstall bash
```

or such. There's a chance that if you damaged a shell file, this will fix it when you log out and log in.

Why reinstall dash?  In Ubuntu, even though I make BASH my shell, it looks like /sbin/sh is provided by dash:

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/sh
diversion by dash from: /bin/sh
diversion by dash to: /bin/sh.distrib
dash: /bin/sh
```

One final thought.  If somebody tries to hack your system and take control of it, one of the things they might do is try to replace your shell. That might explain the trouble you see, although I admit it seems dramatic to bring that up.

Comment: A shell builtin is a command whose functionality is provided by whichever shell you're running (whether it be sh, bash, dash, zsh, or something else). Each shell has its own set of builtins. `$SHELL` is set by the login process to your login shell, whether it is set or not has absolutely no effect on the shell you're currently running.

Comment: @muru Thats news to me. I did not know that the shell program that is running the session can be something different than $SHELL in environment.  I expect that most Ubuntu system users would never see a mismatch between those unless something has gone wrong.  Hopefully, OP will report if he was fiddling about in the environment.  I'm curious to find out.  I suppose a buffer overrun in some script could damage a running shell.

Comment: Fiddling around in their environment? How about installing an additional shell program and using it sometimes? That's not at all uncommon....